# Создание сканера HTML страницы для поиска элемента

Tags: java, html, jsoup, xmlparser

Всем привет, пишу сканер html страницы, который должен получить id исходного элемента -> найти его на странице html -> считать его атрибуты и затем с помощью этих атрибутов найти этот элемент на других страницах с небольшими изменениями в атрибутах.
[image: Схема элемента с его атрибутами]

На картинке красным выделен один и тот же элемент с различными изменениями.
Нужна помощь в составлении алгоритма для поиска элемента на другой странице с использованием исходных атрибутов.
P.S. Использую библиотеку Jsoup

Answer (score 1):

Если ссылка прям настолько отличается, то можно сделать:

1. Поиск элемента по id (Предполагаю будете делать в AsyncTask)
2. Создаем map/модель/json/все что угодно по типу ключ:значение. Или оставить в переменной Element.
3. Записываем все известные аттрибуты(class, href, title, text) и возвращаем наш map(как вариант повесить callback на AsyncTask).
4. На другие страницы передаем наш map, ищем все ссылки (Elements a)
5. По циклу for перебираем все наши ссылки в самом цикла сравниваем каждый по атрибут в map'e с атрибутами ссылки(if...else if...), если атрибут совпал - записываем ссылку (опять же на выбор модель или json или еще что).

Ну а дальше возвращаем наши данные, в 5 пункте так же можно сравнивать парами - больше текста в коде = лучший результат